# Is there a name for the trivial probability distribution P(X=x) = 1 for a unique x?

Tags: probability, terminology

Is there a name for the trivial probability distribution given by $P(X=x) = 1$ for a unique $x$ and $P(X=y) = 0$ for all $y \ne x$? I know it is very trivial, but since it is the distribution that minimizes entropy, I am curious if it has a specific name. (Similar to how a group with one element is referred to as the "trivial group".)

Comment: CDF of that distribution is Heaviside, and PDF is Dirac $\delta$ function.

Comment: @user88595: Would that not refer to $x$ and $y$, respectively, as opposed to the distribution?

Comment: @Kaster: I always thought the Dirac $\delta$ function has $\delta(0) = \infty$ and not $\delta(0) = 1$. Would that make it not a PDF?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, $X$ is called *degenerate* in this case.

Comment: PDF doesn't have to have $PDF(0) = 1$.

Comment: @Kaster "PDF is Dirac δ function." No, there is no PDF.

Comment: @Did It is PDF in terms of generalized functions. Just like delta function is density of unit mass point.

Comment: @Kaster No it is not. And the so-called  "delta function" is not a function, even less a PDF. And mass points have no density with respect to Lebesgue measure. If your teachers told you otherwise, you have been cheated. Sorry.

Comment: @Did if you never heard of generalized functions, I'm sorry too.

Comment: @Kaster *Your ignorance to others too quickly do not ascribe, young padawan*.

Comment: @Did you watched too much SW instead of learning generalized functions, I take. Never too late though. Chop chop, back to school.

Comment: @Kaster Trying hard to be insulting? Sorry, still too basic to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distribution is called *the Dirac measure at $x$*, often denoted by $\delta_x$. Thus, for every $A\subseteq\mathbb R$, $\delta_x(A)=1$ is $x\in A$ and $\delta_x(A)=0$ otherwise.

This distribution has no PDF and its CDF is a Heaviside function, namely, $P(X\leqslant y)=0$ if $y\lt x$ and $P(X\leqslant y)=1$ if $y\geqslant x$.

Comment: Why do you say that "this distribution has no PDF"? It seems to me that $\delta$ defined that way is the PDF.

Comment: Recall that "Dirac's delta function" is actually not a function in the mathematical sense of the term and that Dirac measures are not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure hence they have no PDF.

Comment: What if $A$ is a finite set? In that case would you say there is a PDF? Since the described $\delta$, I believe, will be continuous given the discrete topology of a finite set.

Comment: What do you think D stands for, in [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)?

Comment: "Since the described δ, I believe, will be continuous given the discrete topology of a finite set" Ouch! You are confusing "continuous" in the topological sense with "continuous" as in "continuous distributions". Please do not reinvent the wheel and check at least once the definitions of the field you are interested in, in the present case, probability theory.